# Rest Api to get Products how to pass filter "status" and "visibility"

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

```
$apiUrl = 'http://192.168.1.7/xxxx/api/rest';
```

...

```
$oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);

$resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products?page=1&limit=5";

$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => '*/*'));
$productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());

print_r($productsList);
exit;
```

> I have getting list of product using rest api but i wants a filter
>   with **status=1** and **visibility=4**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this url:

```
$apiUrl/products?page=1&limit=5&filter[status]=1&filter[visibility]=4
```

**[Edit]**
I tried with this url and it worked:

```
$apiUrl/products?page=1&limit=5&filter[0][attribute]=status&filter[0][eq]=1&filter[1][attribute]=visibility&filter[1][eq]=4
```

But before trying make sure that you are allowed to view and filter by status and visibility.
You can set the allowed attributes from System->Web Services->Rest Attributes and select the role you are using (admin, customer or guest).

Comment: not work 400 .Resource collection filtering error.

Comment: Ok. I will try something different and let you know.

Comment: @ravipatel
See my update.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Magento SOAP API which is described below URL:-

**http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.list.html**

which has parameter to pass filter options.

Comment: The OP is asking about the rest api not soap.